# Issue reading values in SwiftUI for a data dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following dictionary:

```
let selection: [String: [String : Bool]]
```

I can display the data as such:

```
ForEach(selection.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) {  item in

    Text("\(item.description)")
        .font(.caption)
        .fontWeight(.bold)

}
```

The above correctly prints the key to the dictionary.

What I am having an issue with is how do I access the values (or remaining portion [String : Bool]) of the dictionary?

Comment: Unrelated but calling `description` on a String is redundant. Just write `Text(item)` and name `item` `key` to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you choose probably depends on what your intent is. Here are a few of ways to access the `[String: Bool]` data. The example is pretty contrived because it's a bunch of different methods stuck together, but it should give you some ideas about ways to access the data.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    let selection: [String: [String : Bool]] = [:]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(selection.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) {  key in
            Text("\(key)")
                .font(.caption)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            let item = selection[key]! //get the [String: Bool] dictionary item
            ForEach(item.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { secondaryKey in
                Text("\(secondaryKey)")
                Text("\((item[secondaryKey] ?? false) ? "true" : "false")")
            }
        }
        
        ForEach(selection.map { ($0,$1) }, id: \.0) { (key, value) in
            Text(key)
            ForEach(value.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { secondaryKey in
                Text("\(secondaryKey)")
            }
            Text("MyKey = \((value["myKey"] ?? false) ? "true" : "false")")
        }
    }
}
```